# Galois group of the polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $G$ be the Galois group of the splitting field of $x^5-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then
>
> 1) $G$ is cyclic
>
> 2) $G$ is non-Abelian
>
> 3) $\vert G \vert =20$
>
> 4) $G$ has an element of order $4$

Here, The splitting field of $x^5-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}\big(\rho.2^{\frac{1}{5}}\big )$ where $\rho=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$.

Hence $\vert G \vert = \vert Gal(\mathbb{Q}\big(\rho.2^{\frac{1}{5}}\big ) : \mathbb{Q} )\vert$= $[\mathbb{Q}\big(\rho.2^{\frac{1}{5}}\big ) : \mathbb{Q} )]$=$20$

So, 3) is true.

1) is clearly false, since $G$ can be realized as a subgroup of $S_5$.

How to prove/disprove 2) and 4) ?

Comment: Can you prove that in $G=\text{Gal}(\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q})$ there is an element with order $5$? What would happen if $G$ were abelian / if $G$ had an element of order-$4$, too?

Comment: Also notice that $1)$ is false, but there are plenty of cyclic subgroups of $S_5$.

Comment: There is no element of order 20 in $S_5$ and hence there is no cyclic subgroup with order 20

Comment: Yes! there exist an element in $G$ with order $5$ by cauchy theorem

Comment: Ok, so *given $3)$*, $1)$ is clearly false.

Comment: You might have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072830/galois-group-of-the-splitting-field-of-the-polynomial-x5-2-over-mathbb-q?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for $1$: The extension $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/5} )/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois.

Hint for $3$: Try and find the generators for $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/5},\rho) / \mathbb{Q})$ by writing out the automorphisms.  Look specifically at

$\sigma = \begin{cases}
2^{1/5} \to 2^{1/5} \\
\rho \to \rho^2
\end{cases}$

Comment: Your hint for 1 actually also settles 2. +1 for IMO well thought out hints.