# Slick proof $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q[e^\frac{2\pi i}p, \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}p]{2}]/\mathbb Q)\cong S_p$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

After having seen a lengthy and painful calculation showing
$\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q[e^\frac{2\pi i}3, \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}]/\mathbb Q)\cong S_3$, I'm wondering whether there's a slick proof $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q[e^\frac{2\pi i}p, \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}p]{2}]/\mathbb Q)\cong S_p$ for odd prime $p$, because these calculations are getting intractable fast.

What are some slick proofs of this fact (assuming it is indeed correct).

**Correction:** What **IS** $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q[e^\frac{2\pi i}p, \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}p]{2}]/\mathbb Q)$ for prime $p$?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the galois group of that extension?

Comment: @M.Van whoopsie! I am!

Comment: The order of that extension is $\;p(p-1)\;$ so the Galois group can **not** possibly be $\;S_p\;$ . In fact, I think it is $\;\cong C_p\rtimes C_{p-1}=\;$  the semidirect product of a  cyclic group of order $\;p-1\;$ by a cyclic group of order $\;p\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I edited the question and asked for a proof

Comment: @DonAntonio perhaps dihedral groups should come up here?

Comment: A dihedral group is the semidirect product of a cyclic group and a cyclic group of order 2. So, it's kind of related.

Comment: @Exterior Perhaps, though I think there is no subgroup of order 10 in this case...but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: In the current form this looks like a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/463671/11619).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your statement does not hold. Let $\zeta$ be some $p$-th root of unity. Remember that the order of the galois group $\text{Gal} \mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2})$ is the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2})/ \mathbb{Q}$. Now $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}]=p-1$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]=p$ because $X^p-2$ is irreducible by eisenstein. We have $[\mathbb{Q}( \zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2} ) ] \leq p$ but $p \mid [ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)][\mathbb{Q}(\zeta): \mathbb{Q}]= [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)](p-1)$, by euclid's lemma we have $p \mid [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)]$ because $ \gcd(p, p-1) =1 $. So $p=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)]$.

Conclusion: $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]=p(p-1)$. Now if your statement would hold, then $p(p-1)=|S_p|=p!$. This is true for odd $p$ exactly when $p=3$. So for any other odd $p$ this is not true.

Comment: @M In order to correctly type the $\;n\,-$ th root write \sqrt[n]{x} ...

Comment: @DonAntonio it feels like there should be an analogously easy way of calculating the galois group of extending by differences of (nonprimitive) roots of unity, i.e finding $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\cos \frac{2\pi i} n)/\mathbb Q)$. Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: Why does $p\mid [ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$ here?

Comment: @Exterior Because $\;[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]2:\Bbb Q]=p\;$

Answer (score 5):

The field $\;K:=\Bbb Q\left(\zeta:=e^{2\pi i/p},\,\sqrt[p]2\right)\;$ is the splitting field of $\;f(x):=x^p-2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , and since this is an irreducible polynomial (why?) then $\;G:=Gal(K/\Bbb Q)\;$ acts transitively over its roots, which are $\;\alpha_i:=\sqrt[p]2\,\zeta^k\;,\;\;k=0,1,2,...,p-1\;$ .

Now take the (Galois) subextension $\;E:=\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q\;$ . This is the cyclotomic extension of the rationals of order $\;\phi(p)=p-1\;$ and it, of course, is cyclic of that order since in fact $\;Gal(E/Q)\cong\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*\;$ .

Likewise, the (non-Galois) subextension $\;F:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]2\,\zeta)/\Bbb Q\;$ of order $\;p\;$ (Why is this extension **not** normal?) is of order $\;p\;$ and its automorphism group is cyclic of order $\;p\;$.

Finally, observe that $\;G=Gal(E/\Bbb Q)\cdot Aut(F/\Bbb Q)\;$ by orders considerations, and since $\;Gal(E/\Bbb Q)\lhd G\;$ we then have a semidirect product $\;\cong C_p\rtimes C_{p-1}\;$

Comment: What are the automorphisms actually doing, i.e how to think of this Galois group?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an 'easy' group it is isomorphic to:

$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} : a, b \in \mathbb{F}_p, a \neq 0 \right\}
$$
with the following isomorphism. If $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta,\sqrt[p]{2}))$ with $\sigma(\zeta)= \zeta^a$ and $ \sigma ( \sqrt{2} ) =  \zeta^b \sqrt[p]{2}$, then send $\sigma$ to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This was actually an excercise in a Galois Theory course I followed this year :)

Comment: I am failing to properly use latex on my phone so anyone edit if you want