# A question about the degree of field extension $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am just beginning my study for field theory and I am trying to solve a problem:

> Let $p$ be a prime and $\zeta$ be the primitive $p$th root of unity. Then calculate $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Here is my attempt:

Since we have $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta)$, we get

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})] [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$$

And this means we only need to calculate $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

For $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[p]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $f(x) = x^p - 2$, and this means

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = \deg(x^p - 2) = p$$

For $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]$, a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ is $\{1, \zeta, \zeta^2,...,\zeta^{p-1}\}$, so we have

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})] = \mid\{1, \zeta, \zeta^2,...,\zeta^{p-1}\} \mid = p$$

Therefore we get

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})] [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = p^2$$

$\textbf{Question:}$ Can someone help me check whether my attempt is right or not? I am just beginning my study and I am really not confident in this. If someone is willing to help, your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This field is the splitting field of $X^p-2$, which has degree $p(p-1)$, see the duplicate. So your second part is not quite right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Galois Group of $x^p - 2$, $p$ an odd prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463671/galois-group-of-xp-2-p-an-odd-prime). See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108395/degree-of-splitting-field-for-fx-xp-2-over-mathbbq-p-prime), without Galois group.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865364/slick-proof-operatornamegal-mathbb-qe-frac2-pi-ip-sqrt-leftroot-2), with the proof for the degree $p(p-1)$ in the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, we have $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\cdots +\zeta^{p-1}=0$, so they can't be a basis. So your line $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]$, a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ is $\{1, \zeta, \zeta^2,...,\zeta^{p-1}\}$, is wrong.