# Uniqueness of automorphisms on root

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, primitive-roots

The following is from A. Białynicki-Birula, "Algebra" (the translation is mine).

> **Example 3**. Let $p$ be a prime number. Let us consider the splitting field $L$ of the polynomial $\frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1}$ over $Q$. The polynomial $f$ is (see p. 214) irreducible in $Q[x]$. The roots of this polynomial are primitive roots of $p$-th degree. Let $\zeta \in L$ be a fixed primitive root of $p$-th degree. Then $L_{f_p} = \{\zeta, \zeta^2, ..., \zeta^{p-1}\}$. For every $i \in N_+$, $1 \le i \le p-1$ there is exactly one automorphism $\alpha \in Aut(L \backslash K)$ such that $\alpha(\zeta) = \zeta^i$. Indeed, the existence of such an automorphism is implied by the theorem 11.3. Besides that, if $\alpha(\zeta) = \beta(\zeta)$ for $\alpha, \beta \in Aut(L \backslash K)$, then for every natural number $j, 1 \leq j \leq p-1$ we have
> $$\alpha(\zeta^j) = (\alpha(\zeta))^j = (\beta(\zeta))^j = \beta(\zeta^j),$$
> hence
> $$\alpha|L_{f_p} = \beta|L_{f_p}.$$
> This - by the final remark of the \$5, example 7, implies that $\alpha = \beta$.
> (...)
> **Example 4**. Let us assume that $n$ is a natural number and that the field $K$ contains $n$ different $n$-th degree roots of unity (thus it contains - by theorem VI.7.9 - a primitive $n$-th degree root). Let $a \in K$; let us consider the polynomial $f=x^n-a \in K[x]$ and let $L$ be the extension of splitting field of this polynomial over $K$. Let us denote by $\sqrt[n]a$ whichever root of polynomial $f$ in the field $L$. Then
> $$K(\sqrt[n]a) = L \text{ and } L_f = \{\sqrt[n]a, \zeta \sqrt[n]a, \zeta ^2 \sqrt[n]a, ..., \zeta^{n-1} \sqrt[n]a\}$$
> where $\zeta$ is any fixed $n$-th degree primitive root. Applying the reasoning similar to that in the example 3 one can easily show that for every integer number $i     $ there exists at most one such an automorphism $\alpha \in Aut(L \backslash K)$ that $\alpha(\sqrt[n]a) = \zeta^i \sqrt[n]a$.

The final remark of the \$5, example 7 says (a bit roughly speaking, but I think that for these needs it is sufficient) that if the restrictions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the set of roots of the polynomial are the same, then $\alpha = \beta$.

Now, how in the case of example 4 the fact that $\alpha (\sqrt[n]a) = \beta (\sqrt[n]a)$ would imply that $\alpha(\zeta^j \sqrt[n]a) = \beta(\zeta^j \sqrt[n]a)$? In the case of example 3, the situation was relatively easy because we had $\alpha(\zeta) = \beta(\zeta)$. Here it seems that $\alpha(\zeta) = \beta(\zeta)$ would also be immediately useful - then we would have $$\alpha(\zeta^j \sqrt[n]a) = \alpha(\zeta)^j \alpha (\sqrt[n]a) = \beta(\zeta)^j \beta (\sqrt[n]a) = \beta(\zeta^j \sqrt[n]a).$$
I tried some other things like raising the whole expression in the parentheses to the $j$-th power, but all these attempts were in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that **both** $x_1:=\root n\of a$ as well as $x_2:=\zeta\root n\of a$ are roots of the polynomial $x^n-a$. So if the restrictions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the set of roots are equal, then we have, in addition to $\alpha(x_1)=\beta(x_1)$ also
$$
\alpha(\zeta)=\alpha(\frac{x_2}{x_1})=\frac{\alpha(x_2)}{\alpha(x_1)}=
\frac{\beta(x_2)}{\beta(x_1)}=\beta(\frac{x_2}{x_1})=\beta(\zeta).
$$
All because we were also given that $\alpha(x_2)=\beta(x_2)$.

In other words, we can write $\zeta$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$. So if we know where both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are mapped, the image of $\zeta$ is also determined.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, so it was basically just about representing $\zeta$ in another way. Can I know how did you get to this solution, was it just something you consider a standard trick or you played with it for a while? BTW, it seems that you mixed up $x_1$ and $x_2$ starting with the second equality (but the response is very clear anyway).

Comment: @TomJohnson Thanks for pointing out the mix-up. Yeah, it is a pretty standard trick. But, we know in advance that any alternative generator (here $\zeta$) of the splitting field **can** be written using the zeros (and field arithmetic). For otherwise it would not be an element of the splitting field. So it is about using the imagination a bit, secure in the knowledge that there is a way. Anyway, a root of unity appears often enough. I'm sure the next time you see it, you will know what to do :-)

Comment: Many examples have been explained on our site earlier. Llike [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463671/11619). I guess the next time I use this particular trick I will mark the answer as CW, which means roughly the same thing as a FAQ :-)

Comment: "any alternative generator of the splitting field can be written using the zeros (and field arithmetic)" - can you elaborate on that? Since if we have a polynomial $f$ over a given field $K$, the splitting field of this $f$ is the least field containing both $K$ and all the roots of $f$, it's clear that any element of the splitting field can be expressed as an expression consisting of field arithmetic operations, elements of $K$ and roots of $f$. You're saying that if we restrict ourselves to generators of the splitting field, then we don't need $K$. How to prove that formally?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am definitely including elements of $K$ as a matter of course.

Comment: OK, I got it. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $Aut(L \backslash K)$, they are identities on $K$ and thus it's trivial that for $x \in K$ we have $\alpha(x) = \beta(x)$ (wasn't needed in that specific case, but in general it can be useful). Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Correct, @TomJohnson.