# Prove $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2+ \omega_p)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

**Que:** Let $ \omega_p = e^{\frac{2\pi \iota}{p}} $ be the $p$-th primitive root of unity, with $p$ some prime. Prove $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2+ \omega_p)$.

**Sol:** To prove the equality we will show one is a subset of the other.
Proving $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p) \subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2+ \omega_p)$ is obvious because $\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p \in Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p) \Rightarrow \sqrt[p]2 + \omega_p \in Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p) \Rightarrow Q(\sqrt[p]2 + \omega_p) \subset Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p)$.
How to prove the other way? Can we work on powers of $\sqrt[p]2 + \omega_p$ to get $\sqrt[p]2$ and $\omega_p$? If there is any other way please tell.

Comment: Try following the ideas of these examples: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#The_theorems

Comment: Are you familiar with the basic Galois correspondence? This field is the splitting field of $x^p-2$ (with [well known Galois group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463671/11619)), so Galois theory works like charm.

Comment: If you don't know Galois theory yet, you can mimick the proof of the primitive element theorem as Arkady commented.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen. Please have a look at my arguments. Since $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p):Q] = p(p-1)$ so $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p)$ is a finite and separable extenstion of $x^p-2$ which means that  $Q(\sqrt[p]2, \omega_p) $ is simple by Primitive Element Theorem. Being simple it will have finitely many intermediate subfields and so by mimicking the proof of primitve element theorem  $Q(\sqrt[p]2+c\omega_p) = Q(\sqrt[p]2+d\omega_p) $ which will lead us to get $\sqrt[p]2,\omega_p \in Q(\sqrt[p]2+c\omega_p)$